# Fill an array with an array?

Tags: c, gcc, raspberry-pi

I'm doing some electronics: I've got 12 RGB LEDs in a circle (i call it the Heel Wheel). I'll be "pulsing" each LED colour in line with pre-defined "levels": see below, LEVEL02 for example means the colour for an LED will get pulsed twice for every 10 cycles... code will cycle through all 12 LEDs one at a time. 1 Cycle = 12 LEDs... 10 Cycles = one colour level loop

Essentially what I want to do is say `pixel[1] = colour1`, or `pixel[5] = colour9` etc... where a `pixel` is my array `heelwheel` below, and `colour` is a set of constant `char` arrays `clRED`, `clRRG` etc... OK, More detail:

```c
// Color Level Definitions

#define LEVEL00 "0000000000" 
#define LEVEL01 "1000000000" 
#define LEVEL02 "1000010000"
```

etc... up to LEVEL10

```c
char heelwheel[12][3]; //wheel pixel: LED, Colour (Red, Green, Blue)

// Colour Definitions: defining mix of colour levels for 12 standard colours 
//(12 coincidentally == the number of LEDs: no particular reason)

const char *clRED[3] = {LEVEL10, LEVEL00, LEVEL00} ; // full red
const char *clRRB[3] = {LEVEL06, LEVEL00, LEVEL04} ; // mostly red, bit of blue
const char *clRAB[3] = {LEVEL05, LEVEL00, LEVEL05} ; // purple
```

etc... for 12 colours

So what I want to be able to do is set each of the 12 "pixels" by specifying 1 of 12 colours... e.g.

```c
heelwheel[0] = clRED ;
heelwheel[1] = clRRB ;
```

I hope it's clear what I'm trying to do... my theory is that I've defined `heelwheel` as a two dimensional array: instead of individually setting the three values in the second dimension, I want to just say `these three values = the three values contained in the three-value colour arrays`

```c
gcc error = "incompatible types when assigning to type char *[3] from type const char **"...
```

I've tried to understand the numerous resources on arrays in C and some stuff is "sticking" but I'm very much a beginner at C, so i'm reaching headache territory quite quickly.

Comment: instead of: heelwheel[0] = clRED ; use memcpy( &heelwheel[0], clRED, sizeof(clRED) );

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go! That could get the tick to answer my question, while "unwinds" answer might make more sense in terms of practicality/standard-practise

Answer (score 0):

Don't use string-like data types for this, since strings are represented as arrays in C and arrays are not assignable.

Encode the color in an integer, the typical choice would be `uint32_t` for full 24-bit RGB, with 8 bits to spare.

Then you'd just have:

```
uint32_t heelwheel[12];
```

And the colours defined like so:

```
/* these assume red in the msbs, blue in the lsbs. */
const uint32_t red = 0xff0000;
const uint32_t purple = 0xff00ff;
const uint32_t yellow = 0xffff00;
/* and so on */
```

And you can assign directly, no problems:

```
heelwheel[0] = red;
heelwheel[1] = purple;
```

Comment: Thanks unwind... so an array can't contain an array? 

I'll roll with your suggestion and see how I go... like I say, it's for electronics, so I need to "pulse" stuff... and I can't really use any more than 10 levels or I'll get "flicker"... I get your approach though: maybe if I use single 30 bit binary numbers... i just need to loop through the three "segments" of 10 bits separately to "pulse" the appropriate colour pin...

Answer (score 0):

> an array can't contain an array?

An array can contain an array (in fact, when you define `char heelwheel[12][3]`, you get an array of 12 arrays of 3 chars), it's just not possible to assign an array to an array by `larray = rarray`, since the C standard says in the section **Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**:

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof`
>   operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to
>   initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of *type*’’ is
>   converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’ that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

But you can achieve what you want by defining

```
const char **heelwheel[12]; //wheel pixel: LED, Colour (Red, Green, Blue)
```

compatibly with your `const char *clRED[3]` etc., because `clRED` etc. have type ‘‘array of pointers to const char’’ which is converted to type ‘‘pointer to pointers to const char’’ which in turn can be assigned by expressions like

```
heelwheel[0] = clRED;
heelwheel[1] = clRRB;
```

after these assignments e. g. `heelwheel[1][2]` is `LEVEL04`.